# On close of Bootstrap modal popup want to set the value of Textbox on main form

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to Bootstrap designing and currently using the Bootstrap v3.1.1 version of it in my ASP.NET MVC5 Project.

I am opening a form on "Edit profile" Click of button and editing some fields such as email.
What I want to do is to reflect them on the main form on close of modal popup.

Here is my code:

```
$('#EditProfile').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
debugger;
var newEmail = $("#txtEmailId").val();
$("#txtEmail").val() = newEmail;// = newEmail;

});
```

Also I am showing email id on main form using following code:

```
<tr>
    <th>Email</th>
        <td>
            <input readonly id="txtEmail" name="txtEmail" type="text" class="form-control"placeholder="Email" size="254" style="width: 200px;"/>
       </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: When i check the value of $("#txtEmailId").val() in alert it is showing me in the alert proper value but it is not reflecting on main form is this happening bacause i have set property of text box as readonly.?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use:

```
$("#txtEmail").val(newEmail);
```

instead of:

```
$("#txtEmail").val() = newEmail;
```

Answer (score 0):

[Bootstrap 3 documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-usage) refers two events you can use

> **hide.bs.modal**: This event is fired immediately when the hide instance method has been called.
>   **hidden.bs.modal**: This event is fired when the modal has finished being hidden from the user (will wait for CSS transitions to complete).

And provides an example on how to use them:

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
   $("#txtEmail").val(newEmail);
});
```

Recommend you to read more on .val() [here](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

*Additional note (not related to your question) Do not use inline style in your html like how you have used this `width: 200px;`*

Answer (score 0):

You have to use :

```
$("#txtEmail").attr('value',newEmail);
```

instead of

```
$("#txtEmail").val() = newEmail;
```

in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#txtEmail").text(newEmail);
```

Or this:

```
$("#txtEmail").html(newEmail);
```